# React Native Expo App: TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I am trying to run my react native expo app on android emulator and getting this error since last day.
Tried everything, deleted node modules and reinstalled.

I am stuck and this is a very critical project for me.
Please any help would be appreciated.

Error:
[Error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77akV.png)

Error on android emulator:
[Error on android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e44UK.png)

My `package.json` file:

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "version": "3.19.25",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src -c .eslintrc --ext js",
    "lint-fix": "eslint src --fix .eslintrc --ext js",
    "start": "expo start",
    "start:prod": "npm start -- --no-dev --minify",
    "android": "npm start -- --android",
    "ios": "npm start -- --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "update-version": "standard-version",
    "deploy": "expo publish",
    "deploy:prod": "npm run deploy",
    "deploy:staging": "npm run deploy -- --release-channel staging",
    "deploy:custom": "npm run deploy -- --release-channel --"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.16",
    "axios": "~0.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "6.22.0",
    "bson-objectid": "1.2.3",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "^47.0.13",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.3.2",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.23.0",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.23",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.14",
    "react-native-date-picker": "2.7.6",
    "react-native-elements": "~2.3.2",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.10",
    "react-native-exceptions-manager": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "4.4.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "8.0.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-renderer": "^15.5.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "2.8.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.9",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "~1.1.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.11",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.2.0",
    "styled-components": "~4.3.2",
    "uuid": "3.3.3",
    "yup": "0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "eslint": "~6.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "~18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "~6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "prettier": "1.14.3",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
    "standard-version": "7.1.0",
    "standard-version-expo": "1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap you App with registerRootComponent(App) like this :

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { View } from 'react-native';

function App() {
  return <View />;
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

source : https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/

Comment: Did that. Still getting the same error.. :(

Comment: have you try deleting the package.lock or yarn.lock files with deleting node_modules folder ?

Comment: let me try that. After adding this registerrootcomponent. I didnt try that. But before I tried 2-3 time

Comment: Still the same error :(